# Cayley-Hamilton says that evaluating an endomorphism's characteristic polynomial over that endomorphism gives zero. Isn't this true by substitution?

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof, cayley-hamilton

Given an endomorphism $f$ of a vector space $V$, its characteristic polynomial, say $P(x)$, is defined as follows: $P(x) = \det(f -xI)$, where $I$ is the identity endomorphism. It is well known that, when we evaluate over $f$, we get $P(f) = 0$, as a consequence of Cayley-Hamilton's theorem.

But, working with the expression directly, we get
$$P(f) = \det(f - fI) = \det(f - f) = \det(0) = 0$$ 
even without Cayley-Hamilton. What's wrong about this?

Comment: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem#A_bogus_%22proof%22:_p(A)_=_det(AIn_%E2%88%92_A)_=_det(A_%E2%88%92_A)_=_0)

Comment: Note: This argument is not too far from being correct(able) though. Working with matrices: The argument above is nearly all that is required to show that CH holds for an upper triangular matrix. The general case is obtained by extending the ground field to an algebraic closure of it. When the field is algebraically closed, all matrices are similar to upper triangular ones, and CH follows easily.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I don't follow. Yes, CH follows easily if the matrix is triangular, but how is this related to the argument in question?

Comment: @user1551 Sorry, I was perhaps unclear. When the characteristic polynomial splits, computing f(A) for an upper triangular matrix is just plugging in $A$ for $x$ in the decomposition of $f$ and computing. That fact that you get $0$ is easy. I see some resemblance to OP's faulty argument here: You just substitute $A$ for $x$, and the computation is nearly just evaluating at each eigenvalue.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong is that $P(x)=\det(f-x\operatorname{Id})$ is a polynomial. Yes, you can compute $P(x_0)$ for a *number* $x_0$ by computing $\det(f-x_0\operatorname{Id})$, but $f$ is not a number; it's an endomorphism.

Conseder, for instance, $Q(x)=\operatorname{tr}(f-x\operatorname{Id})$. By your argument, $Q(f)=0$ too. But, in fact, since $Q(x)=\operatorname{tr}(f)-nx$, you actually have $Q(f)=(1-n)\operatorname{tr}(f)$.

Comment: A slight correction to this answer: it should be $Q(f) = tr(f) - nf$.  @math_noob: If you substitute $f$ first then take the determinant, then the answer you get will be a scalar, but if you first take the determinant to get a polynomial in $x$, then substitute $f$, the answer is a matrix.  So there is no reason to expect them to be the same.

Comment: @Ted Since I defined $Q(x)$ as $\operatorname{tr}(f-x\operatorname{Id})$ and since $\operatorname{tr}$ is linear and $\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{Id})=n$, $Q(x)=\operatorname{tr}(f)-nx$.